# How to translate a c++ structure with #ifndef inside to c# struct

Tags: c#, c++, translate

Hi I have a structure in c++ with some #ifndef inside that I'm not able to translate to c#. It is a very different structure that some others that I have needed to translate before.

```
typedef struct SDK_CONFIG_NET_COMMON_V2
{   
    char HostName[NET_NAME_PASSWORD_LEN];
    char pLocalLinkAddr[32];    
    char pAddr[64];             
    char pGateway[64];

    int HttpPort;

    int TCPPort;    

    int SSLPort;

    int UDPPort;

    int MaxConn;

    int MonMode;

    int MaxBps;

    //char TransferPlan[NET_NAME_PASSWORD_LEN];
    int  TransferPlan;                      
    bool bUseHSDownLoad;                    
    char sMac[NET_MAX_MAC_LEN];             
    char sSn[NET_MAX_MAC_LEN];              
#ifndef WIN32
    int  DeviceType;   
#endif

    int ChannelNum;         
    int Device_Type;    
#ifdef OME
    char Version[NET_MAX_INFO_LEN];        
    SDK_SYSTEM_TIME BuildDate;              
#endif
    char OtherFunction[49];  
    char Manufacturer;  
    char Resume[6];         

}SDK_CONFIG_NET_COMMON_V2;
```

I really appreciate any help, Im really stuck with it.

Comment: C# has `#if` as an equivalent to `#ifdef` but C# does not define the `WIN32` symbol (and I don't know where `OME` comes from) - if you're replicating a struct for a binary API then you should match your target's definition not your own (i.e. find out if your target had `WIN32` and `OME` defined or not)

Comment: Also, if you are defining a struct for P/Invoke you will probably need to know the exact struct layout and if it differs for x64 vs x86, and what encoding to use for the string members.